# How to change child property of parent elements?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I am making the simple game and I can not figure out how to change colors in code .
I have Parent game object where i plan to attach the script to change child element colors.

For example I have this:

```
Parent:A
Childs in A = 1,2;
```

I want to get all 2 elements and change color in first child to black in second to white.

I want to change tag when i change color so I can achieve the random color
 to be on childs.

I don't know how i can get that 2 childs in that parent to change property.

Can i name the childs to 1 and 2 and then look from code for child with gameobject name 1 and change color property , if I can how i can do it ?

Comment: `Child C = gameObject.GetComponent(typeof(Child)) as Child;` could this help?

Comment: OK so you can get the children by looking at the transform, and with a bit of checking you can use `transform.GetChild(n);` to get the first child, or `GetComponentsInChildren<class you need>();` and then set the property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below portion of code is a quick example usage of the GetProperty method. Simply use 
MyGetProperty and MySetProperty as shown below. Remember the variables that will be referenced by a string must be properties.

```
public class Parent {
        private int child1 = 0;
        private int child2 = 0;
        public int iChild1 {
            get {
                return child1; 
            }
            set {
                child1 = value;
            }
        }
        public int iChild2 {
            get {
                return child2;
            }
            set {
                child2 = value;
            }
        }

        public void MainMethod() { 
            MySetProperty("iChild1",1);
            MySetProperty("iChild2",2);
            string strOutput = String.Format("iChild1 = {0} iChild2 = {1}",MyGetPrperty("iChild1"), MyGetPrperty("iChild2"));
        }

        public object MyGetProperty(string strPropName)
        {
            Type myType = typeof(Parent);
            PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(strPropName);
            return myPropInfo.GetValue(this, null);
        }

        public void MySetProperty(string strPropName, object value)
        {
            Type myType = typeof(Parent);
            PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(strPropName);
            myPropInfo.SetValue(this, value, null);
        }

    }
```